# Accessing instance variables from a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have a nodejs serverless project I'm working on and with it I built a custom router to simplify my serverless handlers.

```
class RequestRouter {
  constructor(event) {
    this.routes = {};
    this.request = {
      httpMethod: event.httpMethod,
      pathParameters: event.pathParameters,
      requestedResource: event.resource,
      body: JSON.parse(event.body),
      queryString: event.queryStringParameters,
      route: event.path,
      requestHeaders: event.headers,
     }
  }

  get(resource, callback) {
    this.registerRoute('GET', resource, callback);
  }

  post(resource, callback) {
    this.registerRoute('POST', resource, callback);
  }

  registerRoute(verb, resource, controllerCallback) {
    this.routes[resource+verb] = { method: verb, controller: controllerCallback };
  }

  async routeRequest() {
    var resource = this.request.requestedResource;
    var verb = this.request.httpMethod;

    var route = this.routes[resource+verb];
    if (route == null) {
      return { statusCode: 404, body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Resource not found.' }) };
    }

    return await route.controller();
  }
}

module.exports = {
    RequestRouter
}
```

With this, I can have a dedicated handler per *resource*, without a ton of boiler plate code.

```
var listController = require('./controllers/list_controller');
var common = require('./handler_common');

async function handler(event) {

  var router = new common.RequestRouter(event);
  var controller = new listController.ListController(router.request);

  // Map routes to Controller functions for this handler
  router.get('/lists', controller.getLists);

  // Route the request into the router.
  return router.routeRequest();
};

module.exports.handler = handler
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that I'm passing in a callback for a controller method to the router, which causes the controller method to not be scoped to the controller instance itself. I need the `getLists_byId()` method to be scoped to the instance of the controller so I can access the request object the controller was given through it's constructor.

```
class ListController {
  constructor(request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  // GET: /lists resource route
  async getLists_byId() {
    var requestedListId = this.request.pathParameters.id;
  }
}

module.exports = { ListController };
```

When the code path lands in `getLists_byId()` the `this.request` is undefined.

Is there a way to get around this, other than forcing all controller methods to accept their dependencies? I'd have to pass a repository, request, services, etc into the controller method if that's the case. That would be a different set of problems from the perspective of the generic router.